# matplotlib accessing ax[i] results in TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a custom plot in matplotlib where a subplot is shaded between 0 and a value based on the values from a pandas data column. I have converted this code from using fixed axes values (e.g. `ax1.fillbetweenx()`) to the current code to access parts of the axes array.

However, when I run the function I am receiving a `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` from the following line:

`ax[i].fill_betweenx(well[depth_curve], 0, well['FACIES'], where=(well[curve]==key), facecolor=color)`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The function:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_plot(wellname, dataframe, curves_to_plot, depth_curve, facies_curves=[]):
    num_tracks = len(curves_to_plot)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=num_tracks, figsize=(num_tracks*2, 10))
    fig.suptitle(wellname, fontsize=20, y=1.05)
    
    for i, curve in enumerate(curves_to_plot):
        ax[i].plot(dataframe[curve], depth_curve)

        ax[i].set_title(curve, fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
        ax[i].grid(which='major', color='lightgrey', linestyle='-')
        
        ax[i].set_ylim(depth_curve.max(), depth_curve.min())

        if i == 0:
            ax[i].set_ylabel('DEPTH (m)', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
        else:
            plt.setp(ax[i].get_yticklabels(), visible = False)
        
        if curve in facies_curves:
            for key in lithology_setup.keys():
                color = lithology_setup[key]['color']
                ax[i].fill_betweenx(well[depth_curve], 0, 4, where=(well[curve]==key), facecolor=color)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

The code and sample data:

```py
workingdf = pd.DataFrame({'WELL':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                    'DEPTH':[4300, 4310, 4320, 4330, 4340, 4350, 4360, 4370, 4380, 4390], 
                     'GR':[45, 40, 30, 12, 6, 12, 8, 10, 20, 18], 
                     'FACIES':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]})

lithology_setup = {1: {'lith':'Sandstone', 'color':'#ffff00'},
                 2: {'lith':'Sandstone/Shale', 'color':'#ffe119'},
                 3: {'lith':'Shale', 'color':'#bebebe'},}


curves_to_plot = ['GR', 'FACIES']
facies_curve=['FACIES']
grouped = workingdf.groupby('WELL')

# Create empty lists
dfs_wells = []
wellnames = []

#Split up the data by well
for well, data in grouped:
    dfs_wells.append(data)
    wellnames.append(well)

well = 0

create_plot(wellnames[well], 
            dfs_wells[well], 
            curves_to_plot, 
            dfs_wells[well]['DEPTH'], 
            facies_curve)
```

Below is an example of what the shading will look like in the last subplot from my previous code. This code snippet here is just for colouring the subplot without any hatching.

[image]

Comment: you are trying to index `well` with `well[depth_curve]` and `well[curve]`, but `well=0`. Perhaps you meant to use a different variable other than `well` there?

Comment: My current df has multiple wells in it. I have split up the `workingdf` into individual dataframes and stored them in the list `dfs_wells`. With `well=0` I am accessing the first dataframe in that list.

Comment: I should mention, the code runs and the data plots ok without the for loop at ` if curve in facies_curves:` onwards

Comment: yes, but when you call `create_plot` you don't reassign `well` to anything else, so it is still an `int`. Your error is telling you you can't index that `int`. What are you trying to use for the y value in `fill_betweenx`? because I assume it isn't `0`

Comment: Thanks, @tmdavison. I can see the issue now. I will post up the solution shortly.

Comment: I have changed the code for the fill_betweenx line to: `ax[i].fill_betweenx(depth_curve, 0, dataframe[curve], where=(dataframe[curve]==key), facecolor=color)`
This works in my main code, but not in the example for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tmdavison for his comments. The issue was related to using `well` instead of `dataframe` in the `ax[i].fill_betweenx()` line

The line of code was changed from:

```py
ax[i].fill_betweenx(well[depth_curve], 0, 4, where=(well[curve]==key), 
facecolor=color)
```

to

```py
ax[i].fill_betweenx(depth_curve, 0, 4, where=(dataframe[curve]==key),
                                  facecolor=color)
```

The fixed function is below

```py
def create_plot(wellname, dataframe, curves_to_plot, depth_curve, facies_curves=[]):
    num_tracks = len(curves_to_plot)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=num_tracks, figsize=(num_tracks*2, 10))
    fig.suptitle(wellname, fontsize=20, y=1.05)
    
    for i, curve in enumerate(curves_to_plot):
        ax[i].plot(dataframe[curve], depth_curve)

        ax[i].set_title(curve, fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
        ax[i].grid(which='major', color='lightgrey', linestyle='-')
        
        ax[i].set_ylim(depth_curve.max(), depth_curve.min())

        if i == 0:
            ax[i].set_ylabel('DEPTH (m)', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
        else:
            plt.setp(ax[i].get_yticklabels(), visible = False)
        
        if curve in facies_curves:
            for key in lithology_setup.keys():
                color = lithology_setup[key]['color']
                ax[i].fill_betweenx(depth_curve, 0, dataframe[curve], 
                                  where=(dataframe[curve]==key),
                                  facecolor=color)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Which generates the following plot:

[image]

Also, the original example data was updated to allow the fill to appear.